# Python : How to split the given start date and end date in a dataframe into number of days falling in each month creating new row for every date split

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have the dataframe as shown below which has fields like ID , start and end date.
If we take the ID number 1 , the start and end date is spread across 3 months staring from 15th February till 17th March which is month 2,3 and 4. So I would like to split the dates into 3 parts creating a separate row for every month as shown in the required output below. In total I have approx 30 million unique ID's.

Data -

````
ID  startDate         endDate

1   15/02/2023       17/04/2023

2   10/04/2023       20/06/2023```



Required Output - 


ID  startDate       endDate

1   15/02/2023      28/02/2023

1   01/03/2023      31/03/2023

1   01/04/2023      17/04/2023

2   10/04/2023      30/04/2023

2   01/05/2023      31/05/2023

2   01/06/2023      20/05/2023 ```

Any help would be very much appreciated.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to find a good way to vectorize this operation, so I'm not sure how this will perform across 30 million rows.

```
def split_dates(row):
    row = row.iloc[0]
    months = int(np.datetime64(row.endDate, "M") - np.datetime64(row.startDate, "M"))

    start = np.datetime64(row.startDate, "D")
    end = np.datetime64(row.endDate, "D")

    ends = np.array(
        [start + i * pd.offsets.MonthEnd() for i in range(1, months + 1)],
        dtype="datetime64[D]",
    )
    starts = ends + np.timedelta64(1, "D")

    starts = np.insert(starts, 0, start)
    ends = np.append(ends, end)

    new_df = pd.DataFrame({"startDate": starts, "endDate": ends})

    return new_df


df.groupby("ID").apply(split_dates).reset_index().drop(columns="level_1")
```

Comment: @Micheal Cao - Thanks for your help, would you know why is it giving me an error on this line .......  

ends = np.array(
        [start + i * pd.offsets.MonthEnd() for i in range(1, months + 1)],
        dtype="datetime64[D]",
    )
........
Error Message  - ufunc 'add' cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[D]') and dtype('O')

Comment: You probably have your date columns with type object instead of datetime. Try `df[startDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df[startDate], format = '%d/%m/%Y')` and similarly for endDate

Answer (score 0):

Just making few changes to @Michaels's code to handle the date datatype if incase its a object.

```
    def split_dates(row):
      row = row.iloc[0]
      months = int(np.datetime64(row.endDate, "M") - p.datetime64(row.startDate, "M"))

      start = np.datetime64(row.startDate, "D")
      end = np.datetime64(row.endDate, "D")

      ends = np.array(
      [pd.to_datetime(start + i, format="%Y-%m-%d") + pd.offsets.MonthEnd() for 
      i in range(1, months + 1)],
      dtype="datetime64[D]",
      )
      starts = ends + np.timedelta64(1, "D")

      starts = np.insert(starts, 0, start)
      ends = np.append(ends, end)

      new_df = pd.DataFrame({"startDate": starts, "endDate": ends})

      return new_df


    df.groupby("ID").apply(split_dates).reset_index().drop(columns="level_1")
```